# Moving a replace image with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have replaced my sites logo to another image, however its not in the correct position within the header I have made. I have tried to move the image with padding and/or margin to no resolve. How do I move the image to the left side of the header.

Here is an overlook of the site:

[image]

The following styling has been applied to the image:

```
position: absolute;
height: 120px;
width: 100px;
margin: 0px 200px 0px 0px;
border: 0;
display: block;
color: -webkit-link;
cursor: auto;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
```

The original HTML has been edited through javascript to the image you can see above, I can only use javscript therefore. This means I would like to avoid JQuery and cant use CSS.

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Can you show you HTML code? Without seeing your code I just can tell you to try setting a left:-100px or left:0 depending on your HTML structure.

Comment: If the header has a `position: relative` on it, you can add `top: 0; left: 0;` to your image CSS and it will position it on the top left of the header

Comment: I suggest you also read more into the position property. That will explain why margins and padding did not move your element. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of "position: absolute;" you need to use something like "left: 50px; top: 10px;" to move it around.

Comment: Please add supporting information such as what the element's reference point is. 50px from what? 10px from what? This is an important distinction when using `position: absolute` and requires specific hierarchical structure in order to work as intended.

Comment: Yup, you hit it right on the head there. I was unaware that you had to use top and left as I was using absolute with divs and I was using padding and margin to reposition them.
Thanks to Rocky Sims and everyone for the help :D

Comment: If the question provided the html structure, I would explain my answer within that context. Since it didn't and it sounds like he is wondering why 'padding' and 'margin' aren't moving the image at all, I figured I'd suggest trying 'top' and 'left'.

Comment: Yes, mhodges is right. The parent has to have relative positioning for this to work. But this does answer the initial question.

Comment: And he was completely right, I did not think I would need to provide the HTML seeing as this was a styling issue involving javascript, I will look into the "top and left styling". Thanks again for the help.